# Extract two rows for each unique company name from another large dataset

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013

I have two sheets:

Sheet1 has a list of 300 unique companies that I need to fill records (row of information) for. I need two rows for each company.

Sheet2 has a complete list of 2000+ records for these companies, some companies have a dozen rows of records.

How do I extract two rows for each company name from the large dataset?

It doesn't matter which rows I'm extracting for companies that have more than two rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OFFSET() to move the range past the first match of what you are looking for. It makes the formula a bit messy but it doesn't require VBA.

If you retrieve the first row it just does an Index Match.
Otherwise it does an index match based on the target and match range, both of which are offset by the number of rows which is equal to the first match of the group.

I tried formatting it which hopefully makes it a bit more clear

```
=IF(F2=1,
    INDEX($B$2:$B$60,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$60,0)),
    INDEX(OFFSET($B$2:$B$60,
                 MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$60,0),
                 0),
          MATCH(E2,
                OFFSET($A$2:$A$60,
                       MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$60,0),
                       0),
                0)))
```

Consider the list of Agencies in Column A, the Info in Column B, the Agency Name to lookup in Column E and the instance to look up (1 or 2) in column F.

The output range will look like this

```
E    F    H
1    1    Formula
1    2    Formula
2    1    Formula
...
```

Comment: how did you do such nice formatting with the formula?

Comment: Well, here I just used enter and space but you can insert linebreaks into your formulas with alt+enter in excel. Formatting is much easier in Google sheets though as it uses a monospace font.

Comment: i see, i thought you had some fancy automated way